# Coverting R script to python

Tags: python, r, pandas

Can someone please help me conver [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126327/probability-of-winning-a-game-in-tennis?newreg=2002ecd3269f4cae9a12e19ee88c6e5f)  to python scripts?
I tried line by line but couldn't go any further than the first few lines.

```
from itertools import product 
import pandas as pd
half_state = [0,15,30,40]
score = list(product(a,a))
half_states = pd.DataFrame(score,columns=("opp","own"))

def state(data):
   return (data['own'].map(str) + ':' + data['opp'].map(str)).tolist()
states = state(df)
states.extend(['won', 'lost'])
print(states)
tm = pd.DataFrame(0, index=full_state, columns=full_state)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found a Python module which may be able to help
converting Python to R code
http://www.xavierdupre.fr/app/pyensae/helpsphinx/notebooks/r2python.html

And interfacing Python to R
https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/

I thought you might want to look at the difference between Python and R, [https://shiring.github.io/r_vs_python/2017/01/22/R_vs_Py_post#:~:text=R%20and%20Python%20are%20both,while%20Python%20is%20more%20generalist](https://shiring.github.io/r_vs_python/2017/01/22/R_vs_Py_post#:%7E:text=R%20and%20Python%20are%20both,while%20Python%20is%20more%20generalist).

I believe it's best your spend time learning R script
https://r4ds.had.co.nz/introduction.html